# CSS and Razor View Confusion

Tags: html, css

I am using ASP.NET/MVC with Razor (.cshtml) to create a very basic website. I am new to CSS and want to customize the look and feel of my site, I have inspected the source off the home page and I am getting confused as to how to target/style different elements of the page. The HTML is

```
<div id="navigator">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                 <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/Consultancy">Consultancy</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/Products">Products</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have all of the `<li>` items in my `navigator` class render the same, and have the active item highlighted with orange. However, I am struggling with the correct way to target this component with CSS. My CSS is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-color: #7c7c84;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#navigator li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    transition: background .5s;
}
#navigator li:hover {
    background-color: #4072B4;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius:0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:box-shadow 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#navigator a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigator a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4072B4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#navigator .active {
    color: #FF6500;
}
```

The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Camuvingian/noupqauw/

How can I correctly highlight the .active list item?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the anchor tag since `#navigator .active` does not target the link but the list item's font color.

Anchors have their own color set already by your CSS `#navigator a { color: #fff; }`. So you will need to override it with below CSS.

```
#navigator li.active a { /* Target anchor inside list item which has a class active */
    color: #ff6500;
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/noupqauw/1/)

Comment: Can you just explain this to me please. I assume this is saying, highlight all active li items that are children of `#navigator` and also highlight the containing `a`?

Comment: It is saying highlight all the anchors which are descendant/child of list items `li` which has a class `active` Any doubts? `:)`

Comment: Great stuff thanks. So from "top to bottom" target all elements/anchors that  child items of `li` which are also decedents of `id="navigator"` and override  all `a` anchors which are decedents of both `li` and `id="navigator"`? Sorry, all totally new to me this stuff...

Comment: No problem. Check this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Your comment is right. But if you check the link, you can learn more.